# Show that $\sin n^2$ is divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

## Problem

Show that the number sequence $\sin n^2$ is divergent.

## My Proof

Assume that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin n^2=L.$ Then,

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{+\infty}\cos x {\rm d}x&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{n^2}\cos x {\rm d}x\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k^2}^{(k+1)^2}\cos x {\rm d}x\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\sin(k+1)^2-\sin k^2\right]\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin n^2\\
&=L.
\end{align*}

But, in fact, the infinite integral on the left side is divergent, since $$
\int_0^{+\infty}\cos x {\rm d}x=\lim_{t \to +\infty}\int_0^t\cos x {\rm d}x=\lim_{t \to +\infty}\sin t,$$ the last limit does not exist. Thus, the contradiction comes out.

**Please correct me if I'm wrong.Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Be careful going from a discrete sequence to a continuous variable like that. Note that, for instance, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n^2\pi)$ very much exists.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. It is true that$$\int_0^{+\infty}\cos x\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{n^2}\cos x\,\mathrm dx,$$but with $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$. You are assuming that $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: But I think, for the limit，no matter $n$ goes to the infinity in the "identity" as a integer or as a real number, they are the same.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(2\pi x)\,\mathrm dx$ diverges. However$$\lim_{n\to\infty,\ n\in\mathbb N}\int_0^n\sin(2\pi x)\,\mathrm dx=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your good counterexample. But what if the infinite integral is convergent?

Comment: Then, yes, you have an equality.

Comment: Thus, can I reverse the first part, say, $L=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin n^2=\cdots=\int_0^{+\infty}\cos x {\rm d}x$?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof does not make any sense, both for the fact that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(x)\,dx$ is meaningless and for the fact that the primitive of $\cos(x)$ has very little to do with the behaviour of $\sin(x^2)$ over the integers.

What we *can* say is that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sin(n^2)=L$ implies $L=0$, since the series
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n^2}{n} $$
is convergent by [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality_(number_theory)). In order to actually show that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sin(n^2)$ does not exist, it is enough to prove that the sequence $\{n^2\pmod{\pi}\}_{n\geq 1}$ has an accumulation point which differs from zero. This follows from the fact that the forward difference $(n+1)^2-n^2 = 2n+1$ is [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) $\pmod{\pi}$.